# IntelliJ IDEA - additional fonts with Nexusfont

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts

As I'm working over a Citrix virtual machine, I do not have the rights for installing news fonts.
Therefore I use a program called Nexusfont, that loads fonts on demands while it is running. Eclipse sees those fonts, while IntelliJ not so.
What can I use to reproduce the same effect on IntelliJ? Or better, where does IntelliJ stores its fonts? (like the bundled FiraCode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the fonts inside the `%JDK_PATH%\jre\lib\fonts` solves the problems.